# finding nth combination (incremental approach) of letters (list)

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, dynamic-programming

What is the Pythonic way of finding the nth combination given a list of alphabets?

```
# a = list("abc")
```

Expected output (compinations):

```
# a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc, aaa, aab, aac, and so on... (until the nth)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nth"?  Have you looked at the itertools powerset recipe?

Comment: I'm keeping a count of all the combinations, so when I have the required number of combinations, I would terminate the loop

Comment: the problem with powerset is that it breaks after ('a','b','c') but I do want to continue after ('a','b','c'), to ('a','a','a','a') and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With itertools, generating all the combinations along the line:

```
def powerprod(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    for r in itertools.count(1):
        for c in itertools.product(s, repeat=r):
            yield c
```

Demo:

```
>>> map(''.join, itertools.islice(powerprod('eht'), 34))
['e', 'h', 't', 'ee', 'eh', 'et', 'he', 'hh', 'ht', 'te', 'th', 'tt', 'eee', 'eeh', 'eet', 'ehe', 'ehh', 'eht', 'ete', 'eth', 'ett', 'hee', 'heh', 'het', 'hhe', 'hhh', 'hht', 'hte', 'hth', 'htt', 'tee', 'teh', 'tet', 'the']
```

**Update**

AFAIK, @gnibbler approach won't work, as do not distinguish between `001` and `1` and similar combinations. Here is a faster way to get only n'th combination :

```
from itertools import product, islice

def max_sum_n_pow_lower_x(x, n):
    """ returns tuple of number of summand and maximal sum
        of form `n` + `n`**2 + `n`**3  not greater than `x` """
    i, c, s = 1, 0, 0
    while s < x:
       i *= n
       c += 1
       s += i
    return c-1, s-i

def get_nth_pow(iterable, n):
    l = list(iterable)
    repeat, start_from = max_sum_n_pow_lower_x(n, len(l))
    prod = itertools.product(l, repeat=repeat+1)
    return ''.join(list(islice(prod, n-start_from))[-1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> get_nth_pow('eht', 34)
'the'
```

Comment: Instead of islicing `product`, once you have the sum of the geometric progression, you can subtract that from `n` and *then* you can use the base expansion.

Comment: @DSM probably yes, I thought about it. But I'm a bit tired to implement it right now :)

Comment: can it also handle max int's like "4125383079316"? Seems to be raising an error

Comment: raises a "ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= maxint"

Comment: @Vanthewilderperson hey, that requirement wasn't included in the specification :) See DSM comment

Answer (score 4):

Your examples are base3 numbers.

convert `n` to base3 (or whatever the length of the alphabet). Then replace the "digits" with the symbols from *your* alphabet.

This allows you find the nth value without generating all the previous n-1 entries

Comment: This is a pretty clever approach.  Kudos.  I like it.

Comment: These are not base 3 numbers. They are [*bijective* base 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration), as 012 is distinct from 12.

Comment: how do you exactly replace the "digits" with the alphabets! Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @alko Do you have any recommendation, about how can replace the "digits" with the symbols from the alphabets?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So then they are just base 4 where 0 is nil, 1 is 0, 2 is 1, and 3 is 2?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: No. Bijective base 3 is very different from base 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def gen_combinations(alphabet):
  n = 1
  while True:
    for item in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(alphabet, n):
      yield ''.join(item)
    n += 1

print list(itertools.islice(gen_combinations("abc"), 20))
```

(This requires Python 2.7, but can be easily rewritten for earlier versions of itertools.)

Comment: doesn't generate the right combinations, for "eht" and n=34, the last combination should be "the", which does not match

Answer (score 1):

As [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) commented on gnibbler's answer, what you want to use is a [bijective number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration), where the characters in your alphabet are the digits.

Here's how you can do this in code:

```
import math

def get_bijective_val(n, alphabet):
    base = len(alphabet)
    digits = []
    while n:
        remainder = math.ceil(n/base)-1
        digits.append(n - remainder*base)
        n = remainder
    digits.reverse()
    return "".join(alphabet[digit-1] for digit in digits)
```

This should work efficiently even for very large numbers or long alphabets. Its running time is proportional to the length of the output string, or the `log` of the integer in a base equal to the length of the alphabet.

Here's an example run:

```
>>> for i in range(40):
    print(i, get_bijective_val(i, "eht"))


0 
1 e
2 h
3 t
4 ee
5 eh
6 et
7 he
8 hh
9 ht
10 te
11 th
12 tt
13 eee
14 eeh
15 eet
16 ehe
17 ehh
18 eht
19 ete
20 eth
21 ett
22 hee
23 heh
24 het
25 hhe
26 hhh
27 hht
28 hte
29 hth
30 htt
31 tee
32 teh
33 tet
34 the
35 thh
36 tht
37 tte
38 tth
39 ttt
```

Comment: this is a really nice solution. could you please tell me how I could modify it for only unique combinations where each item only occurs once? (i.e: a,b,ab for alphabet 'ab')

Comment: @apfz: I don't think there's any connection between that problem and this one. The bijective number system is infinite, having a representation of every natural number, whereas your set of non-repeating strings is very finite.

Comment: thank you for that. I will have a closer look. I have posted a separate question as well in case you or someone is interested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502368/how-to-get-combination-by-index-from-a-list-of-unique-combinations/73503204