# How to get combination by index from a list of unique combinations

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, combinatorics, bijection

The following is what I am trying to achieve:

```
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
items = ['item-a','item-b'...'item-n']
my_map = defaultdict()

for i, item in enumerate(items):
        my_map[alpha[i]] = item
```

Here, I am creating a dictionary where each item is mapped against a single character. Every possible combination (i.e. ab7, so 3 items) can randomly be picked after which its value will be processed.

For n items a total of 2^n combinations exist. So for 6 items, the total of combinations that can be picked looks as follows:

```
['a','b','ab'....'bef'...'abcdef']
```

**NOTE:** combinations only occur once. In this situation `'ba'` is the same as `'ab'`, therefor only `'ab'` exists in the list.

Suppose I have the index of the combination, how can I get the combination that belongs to that index without calculating all possible combinations?

I have played around with the following but this only works for all possible combinations

```
import math

def get_bijective_val(n, alphabet):
    base = len(alphabet)
    digits = []
    while n:
        remainder = math.ceil(n/base)-1
        digits.append(n - remainder*base)
        n = remainder
    digits.reverse()
    return "".join(alphabet[digit-1] for digit in digits)

get_bijective_val(50,'abcdef')
```

(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446640/1251070)

I have tried to modify it but am unable to find the solution

This is the expected result:

```
>>> print(get_bijective_val(0, 'abcdef'))
>>> 'a'
>>> print(get_bijective_val(50, 'abcdef'))
>>> 'bef'
>>> print(get_bijective_val(63, 'abcdef'))
>>> 'abcdef'
```

Comment: How do you define unique? Are "ab" and "ba" the same in your scenario?

Comment: @eike Fair point, they are considered the same

Comment: Please explain what you mean by the combination of a particular index?  Do you mean you want to find the permutations of the letters at a specific index in my_list?  Do you mean that given an alphabet string find the number of combinations if taken index in size?  Please provide the expected output given your input sample.  also, it would be helpful if you could walk us through the logic you are trying to implement

Comment: The answer relies heavily on the order of the combination list. Do you have a method of constructing that list? If so, it may be possible to adapt a way to retrieve the nth element from that

Comment: @eike The order of the list of combinations is alphabetical and by length of character set, so: 'a','b','c'...,'ab','ac','bc'...'abcdef' etc

Comment: @eike I have updated my question with the desired output and an explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @itprorh66 please see my updated question

Comment: So you want a fast method of calling `[x for i in range(len("abcdef")+1) for x in combinations("abcdef", i)][n]`?

Comment: @eike yes, without having to compute every single combination. hence the attached code example was a really good start (extremely fast)

Comment: @apfz while it only computes the unique combinations, it still computes all 64 of them instead of just computing one. I believe this can be done much faster, but some combinatorics will be involved.

Comment: @eike the reason why I can't compute all of them is because I am working with much larger datasets ('abc....z0123' etc). The 64 items was just a practical example, but yes I am looking for a scalable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For larger alphabets this algorithm is much faster than generating all combinations with itertools, but there is probably still a lot of potential for optimizations:

```
from math import factorial


def get_combination(alphabet, index):
    """Finds the nth combination of any length"""
    alphabet = list(alphabet)
    n = len(alphabet)
    k = 0

    # Find length of combination (k)
    while k <= n:
        combination_count = n_choose_k(n, k)
        if index < combination_count:
            # index is within combinations of length k
            break
        else:
            # index is within combinations of length > k
            index -= combination_count
            k += 1
    if k > n:
        raise Exception("Index out of range")

    return get_k_combination(alphabet, int(k), index)


def get_k_combination(alphabet, k, index):
    """Finds the nth combination of length k"""
    combination = []
    for elem in range(k):
        n = len(alphabet) - 1
        k_ = k - elem - 1
        i = 0
        while n - i >= k_:
            combination_count = n_choose_k(n - i, k_)
            if index < combination_count:
                combination.append(alphabet[i])
                alphabet = alphabet[i + 1:]
                break
            else:
                index -= combination_count
                i += 1
    return combination


def get_combination_bruteforce(alphabet, index):
    return list(
        [
            x
            for i in range(len(alphabet)+1)
            for x in combinations(alphabet, i)
        ][index]
    )


def n_choose_k(n, k):
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(n - k) * factorial(k))
```

Small CLI and benchmarks [here](https://git.rcx.one/eike/combinatorics/src/branch/master/comb.py)

For an alphabet of length 15, `get_combination` took 0.228s and `get_combination_bruteforce` took 39.525s to find all possible combinations one by one (173 times speedup).

It works by first finding out how long the combination with the given index is and then reconstructing it element-wise:

1. The combinations are primarily sorted by length and we know that there are `n over k` combinations of length `k`, where `n` is the alphabet size. So we find the length by subtracting `n over k` for increasing `k` from the given index until it goes negative. The last `k` is the length of the requested combination.
2. Since the combinations are secondarily sorted by the alphabet order, we know that each element in a combination is only followed by higher elements. So for a combination of length `k` starting with the `x`-th element of the alphabet, the remaining combination elements have to be chosen from `alphabet[x+1:]`. With this information we can reconstruct each element like we calculated `k` before.

There may be a closed form solution to both of these steps, but I won't be the one to find it.

Comment: Very interesting, let me dive into this and have a closer look. I really appreciate the support and effort

Comment: @apfz note that the `n_choose_k` implementation was previously working with floats, which produced wrong results for sufficiently high `n` (numerical instability). This is fixed by using `//` instead of `/`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the ordering of results you were after, but I think this is what you are after:

```
def get_bijective_val(n, alphabet):
    return "".join(letter for i, letter in enumerate(alphabet) if (n >> i) & 1)
```

This simply includes the `i`th character in the alphabet when the `i`th bit in the binary representation of `n` is a `1`.

The `(n >> i) & 1` expression uses bit manipulation to do this (right shift and bitwise AND), but you can do it with regular division and subtraction if you find that easier.

Here's a more verbose version, using only modolo (`%`) and integer division (`//`) instead of bit manipulation:

```
def get_bijective_val(n, alphabet):
    digits = []

    n_binary_digits = []
    while n:
        n_binary_digits.append(n % 2)
        n = n // 2

    for n_binary_digit, letter in zip(n_binary_digits, alphabet):
        if n_binary_digit == 1:
            digits.append(letter)

    return "".join(digits)
```

Output of `print([get_bijective_val(i, "abcdef") for i in range(64)])`:

```
['', 'a', 'b', 'ab', 'c', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc', 'd', 'ad', 'bd', 'abd', 'cd', 'acd', 'bcd', 'abcd', 'e', 'ae', 'be', 'abe', 'ce', 'ace', 'bce', 'abce', 'de', 'ade', 'bde', 'abde', 'cde', 'acde', 'bcde', 'abcde', 'f', 'af', 'bf', 'abf', 'cf', 'acf', 'bcf', 'abcf', 'df', 'adf', 'bdf', 'abdf', 'cdf', 'acdf', 'bcdf', 'abcdf', 'ef', 'aef', 'bef', 'abef', 'cef', 'acef', 'bcef', 'abcef', 'def', 'adef', 'bdef', 'abdef', 'cdef', 'acdef', 'bcdef', 'abcdef']
```

Comment: This is amazing. thank you so much. Struggled to get it right., but this works like a charm! Much appreciated.

Comment: @apfz This is not the order you specified in your comment ('a','b','c'...,'ab','ac','bc'...'abcdef' etc)

Comment: @eike whoops you are right...

Comment: @apfz So does this answer your question or not? Should anybody still look into it or are you satisfied?

Comment: @eike No, it isn't answered yet and yes it looks like I still need a little help

Comment: @Oli any idea how I could solve the sorting from your example?

Comment: @apfz I'm working on it - I've got an idea for how to do it in `O(n^2)` time complexity where `n` is the length of the function output, but trying to think if I can do better

Comment: @apfz Just finding a general way to integrate the figuate number fomulae for the r-dimensional simplices, then I'll be done! (Wow, what a rabbit-hole! I'm probably overcomplicating this...)

Comment: @Oli Your approach sounds very interesting. Definitely worth a vacation to the rabbit hole. I have bookmarked this.